# forEach() method in Javascript for key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, foreach, javascript-objects, getelementbyid

How to print only the value(s) in the display?

```js
let room1 = new Map();
room1.set("candles", 8)
room1.set("fridge", 1)
room1.set("washing machine", 3)
room1.set("chairs", 4)
room1.set("sofa", 2)
room1.set("jacuzzi", 6)

let text4 = "";
room1.forEach(function(key) {
  text4 += key + "<br>"
});

document.getElementById("demo8").innerHTML = text4;
```

```html
<p id="demo8"></p>
```

Comment: Use the second argument of forEach: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach. I assume you meant print the keys, not values.

Comment: The OP actually already is printing the values. The OP just got the naming wrong. The mapping functions first parameter is the `value` of a map's entry. The second parameter is the `key`. The OP even is using [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) like this. Each word serves as `key`(1st parameter), each integer serves as `value` (2nd parameter). The OP also can immediately countercheck with logging either of `[... room1.keys()]`,`[... room1.values()]`, `[... room1.entries()]`.

Answer (score 2):

It's 2022. Forget `forEach` and use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). It gets key-value pairs when iterating over a `Map`:

```js
let room1 = new Map();
room1.set("candles", 8)
room1.set("fridge", 1)
room1.set("washing machine", 3)
room1.set("chairs", 4)
room1.set("sofa", 2)
room1.set("jacuzzi", 6)

let text4 = "";
for(let [key,value] of room1) {
  text4 += `${key} - ${value}<br>`; // this could be key+" - "+value+"<br>" of course
};

document.getElementById("demo8").innerHTML = text4;
```

```html
<p id="demo8"></p>
```

Comment: ... _"It's 2022. Forget `forEach` and use `for...of`. It gets key-value pairs when iterating over a Map:"_ ... A  [map's `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) does exactly the same; it does consume/operate exactly the `map`s  same `Iterator` object, here ... [`room1[Symbol.iterator]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator) .., and provides for each entry the key-value pair as the callback function's parameters ... `(value, key, map)`

Comment: @PeterSeliger thanks, mea culpa! I even tried it, but in the wrong way, and without checking the documentation. I can't really say I like `forEach()` more now than before.

Answer (score 1):

##### There're some solutions, follow four possibilities...

**1)** For a [better performance](https://leanylabs.com/blog/js-forEach-map-reduce-vs-for-for_of/) use `for...of` instead `forEach`:

```
for(let [key] of room1) {
    text4 += key + "<br>";
};
```

**2)** Short code (*spread syntax*) to get the `keys` of your `Map` and convert to `Array`:

```
[...room1.keys()].forEach(function(key) {
    text4 += key + "<br>"
});
```

**3)** The same of first solution but with `Array.from(...)` explicit:

```
Array.from(room1.keys()).forEach(function(key) {
    text4 += key + "<br>"
});
```

**4)** Add the first parameter `value` to `forEach` function:

```
room1.forEach(function(value, key) {
    text4 += key + "<br>"
});
```

Example:

```js
let room1 = new Map();
room1.set("candles", 8)
room1.set("fridge", 1)
room1.set("washing machine", 3)
room1.set("chairs", 4)
room1.set("sofa", 2)
room1.set("jacuzzi", 6)

let display = document.getElementById("demo8");
for (let [key] of room1) {
  display.innerHTML += key + "<br>";
};
```

```html
<p id="demo8"></p>
```

#### Reference:

- [How to use .map() over Map keys in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57642099/how-to-use-map-over-map-keys-in-javascript)
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-map-foreach-method/

Comment: The naming of the mapping function's parameters got swapped/interchanged ... it has to be `... forEach(function(value, key) { ...` instead of `... forEach(function(key, value) { ...` ... Thus the result should be a list of integers since the integers are the map's values and the words are its keys.

Comment: It really makes sense, I made the correction, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

You could get only the keys directly.

```js
let rooms = new Map();
rooms.set("candles", 8)
rooms.set("fridge", 1)
rooms.set("washing machine", 3)
rooms.set("chairs", 4)
rooms.set("sofa", 2)
rooms.set("jacuzzi", 6)

console.log([...rooms.keys()]);
```